# Mongo not working with node.js program

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to create a simple node.js program to input, update and delete "name and job" records of people and show the same in browser. I'm using node.js, mongo and jade.

Following is my server.js file (in the "/base" folder):

```
var express= require("express"),
http= require("http"),
bodyparser= require("body-parser"),
mongo= require("mongodb");

var app= express();
db= new mongo.Db("newapp", new mongo.Server("127.0.0.1", "27017"), 
                           {safe:true}, {auto_reconnect: true});

var people= db.collection("people");

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get("/", function(req, res){
    people.find().toArray(function(err, docs){
            if(err) 
                throw err;
            res.render("index.jade", {people: docs});   
    });
});

app.post("/", function(req, res){
    people.insert({name: req.body.name, job: req.body.job}, 
            function(err, doc){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    res.redirect("/");
            });
});

app.get("/update/:id", function(req, res){
    people.findOne({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)}, 
            function(err, doc){
                    if(err) 
                        throw err;
                    res.render("update.jade", {person: doc});
            });
});

app.post("/update/:id", function(req, res){
    people.update({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)},
            {
                    name: req.body.name,
                    job: req.params.job
            },  function(err, item){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    res.rediect("/");
            });
});

app.get("/delete/:id", function(req, res){
    people.remove({_id:new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)},
            function(err){
                    if(err)
            throw err;
            res.redirect("/");
            });
});

app.listen("3000", function(){
    console.log("Now Listening on port: 3000");
});
```

I have an index.jade file (in the "/base/views/" sub-folder):

```
form(method="POST")
    p Name:
        input(type="text", name="name")

    p Job:  
        input(type="text", name="job")

    p: button Add

if(typeof(people)!=="undefined")
    ul
            each person in people
                    li
                        h2= person.name+ " ("+ person.job+ ")"
                        p
                            a(href="/update/#{person._id}") Update
                            a(href="/delete/#{person._id}") Delete

else
    p No People
```

My update.jade file (in the "/base/views/" sub-folder) is:

```
form(method="POST")
    p Name:
            input(type="text", name="name", value="#{person.name}")

    p Job:  
            input(type="text", name="job", value="#{person.job}")

    p: button Update
```

When I do localhost:3000 in the browser, it says

```
GET http://localhost:3000/ net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

Any help is much appreciated, thanks a lot!

Comment: First of all check mongo is running or not.
Then make change "localhost" instead of "127.0.0.1"
and make sure port 3000  is free! and it should be number

Comment: Hmm, did all those changes, mongo is running, port 3000 is free; same error: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Please check, whether your port 3000 is already bind or not - using -``netstat -an | grep LISTEN | grep -v ^unix``

Comment: also check - whether http://127.0.0.1:3000/ isgiving the same error or not?

Comment: 127.0.0.1:3000 is giving the same error. port 3000 is not bound except when I run node server.js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I had not opened the database in the program. db.open(function(err, db){....}); is the missing part.

Working code:

```
var express= require("express"),
http= require("http"),
bodyparser= require("body-parser"),
mongo= require("mongodb");

var app= express(), 
db= new mongo.Db("newapp", new mongo.Server("localhost", "27017"), 
                             {safe:true}, {auto_reconnect: true});

app.use(bodyparser.urlencoded({extended: true}));

db.open(function(err, db){
    if(err)
        console.log(err);

    people= db.collection("people");

    app.get("/", function(req, res){
        var cursor= people.find();
        cursor.toArray(function(err, docs){
            if(err) 
                throw err;
            res.render("index.jade", {people: docs});   
        });
    });

    app.post("/", function(req, res){
        people.insert({name: req.body.name, job: req.body.job}, 
            function(err, doc){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    res.redirect("/");
            });
    });

    app.get("/update/:id", function(req, res){
        people.findOne({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)}, 
            function(err, doc){
                    if(err) 
                        throw err;
                    res.render("update.jade", {person: doc});
            });
    });

    app.post("/update/:id", function(req, res){
        people.update({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)},{
                    name: req.body.name,
                    job: req.body.job
            }, function(err, item){
                    if(err)
                        throw err;
                    res.redirect("/");
            });
    });

    app.get("/delete/:id", function(req, res){
        people.remove({_id: new mongo.ObjectID(req.params.id)},
            function(err){
            if(err)
                throw err;
            res.redirect("/");
            });
    });
});

app.listen(3000, function(){
    console.log("Now Listening on port: 3000");
});
```

The index.jade (in views folder) is:

```
form(method="POST")
    p Name:
        input(type="text", name="name")

    p Job:  
        input(type="text", name="job")

    p: button Add

if(people!==NULL)
    ul
        each person in people
                li
                    h2= person.name+ " ("+ person.job+ ")"
                    p
                        a(href="/update/#{person._id}") Update&nbsp
                        a(href="/delete/#{person._id}") Delete

else
    p No People
```

The update.js (in views folder) is:

```
form(method="POST")
    p Name:
            input(type="text", name="name", value="#{person.name}")

    p Job:  
            input(type="text", name="job", value="#{person.job}")

    p: button Update
```